# Crystal Reports: How to suppress all records in group if ONE based off the value of 1 field

Tags: crystal-reports, null, report, suppression

I have a report which lists all employee timesheets (grouped). Each employee will have a record for each day (5 records in total) per group. I want to suppress ALL records for a employee if ANY of the 5 records has a value in a particular field (called "uniqueAttachID").

Basically, if the "uniqueAttachId" is blank, it tells me that the record does not have an attachment and I want to see all employees where this is the case. The attachment can be added to ANY of the 5 records therefore, if ANY of the records HAS data is this field, then I want the whole section of the group suppressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below trick to achieve your requirement,

1] create a **summary** on **uniqueattachedID** across the group. This summary will give you sum of uniqueattachedID column. Suppress this summary.

2] Now go to the **Section Expert** of the group. Write formula for Suppress.

3] In formula you will write

```
if summary column (select this from reports field) > 0 then true 
else false
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress ALL records (Group and Detail), you will have to go into Section Expert, and in the suppress formula for each section of your report that you want to suppress, you enter

```
uniqueAttachID <> ""
```

That will suppress each section if uniqueAttachID has a value. You may need to adjust the formula if uniqueAttachID is a numeric field.